Getting error related to lazy loading when adding many to many relationship
I'm struggling with SQLAlchemy. I have a model with a many to many relationship set up:
class User(Base):
    roles: Mapped[List["Role"]] = relationship(
        secondary="user_roles", back_populates="users"
    )

I'm setting up some code to populate the database with test data:
    user = await register_user(
        email="me@email.com", username="username", password="test1234"
    )
    db_session.add(user)
    await db_session.commit()

    admin_role = Role(name="Admin", owner_id=user.id)
    db_session.add(admin_role)

    user.roles.append(admin_role)
    db_session.add(user)
    await db_session.commit()

But when I do this, I get
sqlalchemy.exc.MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place?

There's a link with that error which suggests that the problem is lazyloading. But in this case, I didn't load anything. I'm confused as to how to establish the cross model relationship.
I'm using the asyncpg driver to run on Postgres and have the sessionmaker set to use autocommit=False, expire_on_commit=False.

Probably referencing user.id because user is expired on commit.  I think appending the role should be sufficient after adding. This can be configured by toggling expire on commit.
You can try this:

    user = await register_user(
        email="me@email.com", username="username", password="test1234"
    )
    db_session.add(user)
    await db_session.commit()

    admin_role = Role(name="Admin")
    db_session.add(admin_role)

    user.roles.append(admin_role)
    await db_session.commit()


It's not the id. The stack trace is pointing to the the append line.

Maybe include the stack trace and also turn echo to true on the engine and see what's happening before the error.

Also maybe include which engine you are using and how it is configured.
